# How to enable GLX and EGL integration with XCB for Qt5 applications in Yocto Linux?

Tags: qt, opengl, bitbake, egl, xcb

I have an application running on Yocto Zeus 3.0.1 with Qt5 and relies on OpenGL EGL. The application builds fine, but fails with the following message:

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform offscreen surface, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
```

I have added all the needed OpenGL drivers in image `.bb` file:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "libegl-mesa libgl-mesa libegl-mesa-dev libgl-mesa-dev libgles3-mesa-dev mesa-megadriver"
```

The following is my `qt5/qtbase_%.bbappend` file.

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

PACKAGECONFIG_append = "gles2 mtdev sql-sqlite glib fontconfig gif accessibility"

PACKAGECONFIG_append = " widgets"

do_configure_prepend () {
    cat >> ${S}/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++/qmake.conf <<EOF
    # the below indentation is important - Soham

QMAKE_LIBS_EGL += -lEGL -ldl -lglib-2.0 -lpthread
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2 += -lGLESv2 -lgsl -lEGL -ldl -lglib-2.0 -lpthread

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -DLINUX=1 -DWL_EGL_PLATFORM -DEGL_API_FB=1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DLINUX=1 -DWL_EGL_PLATFORM -DEGL_API_FB=1

QT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM = xcb
load(qt_config)
EOF
}
```

I am building the application on the target itself. Therefore, I added the `-dev` files.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I do not know how, but can you enable Qt's debug output? There is some code like this in `QXCBConnection`'s constructor: `qCDebug(lcQpaGl) << "Failed to initialize xcb gl-integration" << glIntegrationNames.at(i);` However, I only see code saying that something went wrong, but nothing that would print an error message...

Comment: I enabled QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1. Then I did not get any such output what you said. But these are some of the outputs that I am getting:
`loaded library /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`
`qt..qpa.xcb: xcb_)shm_create_segment() failed for size 3023616`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to change my `qtbase_%.bbappend`. It should look like the following:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

IMAGE_FEATURES += "accessibility"
IMAGE_FEATURES += "gles2 mtdev sql-sqlite glib fontconfig gif accessibility xcb egl libs xkb xkmcommon"
QT_CONFIG_FLAGS_APPEND = "-xcb"

PACKAGECONFIG_append = " widgets"

DEPENDS += "gsl libxkbcommon"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "gsl xrandr libxkbcommon"

do_configure_prepend () {
    # the below indentation is important - Soham
    cat > ${S}/mkspecs/oe-device-extra.pri <<EOF

QMAKE_LIBS_EGL += -lEGL -ldl -lglib-2.0 -lpthread -lX11 -lxcb -lXrandr -lxcb-glx
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2 += -lGLESv2 -lgsl -lEGL -ldl -lglib-2.0 -lpthread -lX11 -lxcb -lXrandr -lxcb-glx

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -DLINUX=1 -DWL_EGL_PLATFORM -DEGL_API_FB=1 -DXCB_USE_EGL -DXCB_USE_GLX
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DLINUX=1 -DWL_EGL_PLATFORM -DEGL_API_FB=1 -DXCB_USE_EGL -DXCB_USE_GLX

QT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM = xcb
QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION = xcb_egl

EOF
}
```